# how to prove $f$ is an arithmetic function with this property $\sum_{d\mid n} f(d)=n^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic-functions

how to prove $f$ is an arithmetic function with this property
$$\sum_{d\mid n} f(d)=n^2$$

[Arithmetic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_function)

Comment: I think it's a direct result of [Möbius inversion formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Möbius_inversion_formula)

Comment: @frank why? ${  }$

Comment: Are you trying to *find* a function $f$ with this property or do you have a function and you want to show it has this property? Currently unclear.

Comment: $f$ with this property is Arithmetic function ?

Comment: Dear elham, The notion of *arithmetic function* is not well-defined enough to give a precise answer to your question.  If you forced me to choose, I'd say "yes", the function $f$ is an arithmetic function, but a slightly obscure one.  Regards,

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Dear Michael, I'm not sure your edit maintained the meaning of the question.  I think the OP is asking if the function $f$ defined in this way satisfies the (imprecise) definition of *arithmetic function* from the linked wikipedia page.  Regards,

Comment: @MattE : So how did the meaning change.  He wrote "how to prove $f$ is Arithmetic function with this property".  I changed it to "how to prove $f$ is an arithmetic function with this property".  Where is there a change in meaning?  (I also slightly improved the mathematical notation.)

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Dear Michael, You're right; I'm sorry.  I conflated what I'd inferred from comments with what I (mis)remembered was in the original text.  Maybe my (unfair) complaint was just that the text of the question hadn't been pushed closer to what I think is actually being asked (although perhaps I am wrong on that too). Best wishes,

Comment: @draks... Oh, sorry, I misunderstood. Now it seems that the propose of OP is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think by saying arithmetic function,OP means that $f(1)=1$ and for all $a,b,$
$$(a,b)=1 \Rightarrow f(a)f(b)=f(ab).\tag1$$
From  Möbius inversion formula as Frank Science commented,
$$f(n)=n^2\sum_{d|n}{\dfrac{u(d)}{d^2}}=n^2\prod_{p|n}{(1-\frac{1}{p^2})},\tag2$$ 
for every $n\geq1.$

Now it's obvious that $f(1)=1$,and $(1)$ is hold.Hence $f(n)$ is an arithmetic function.

Comment: I think this answer should be accompanied by accepted understandings of what "arithmetic function" means (typically any function $f:{\bf N}\to{\bf C}$ that is related to the structure of the integers, i.e. arithmetic information), and a note of the fact that the property characterized by $(1)$ is referred to as *multiplicative* (as a label that is applied to arithmetic functions).

Comment: @anon,if not,what's OP's meaning then?Maybe we should close this question until OP edit it?

Comment: It appears that OP had linked to the Wikipedia article to begin with, so it would seem OP's understanding of the term agrees with everyone else's more or less. My original interpretation of the question is how to know there even *exists* such an $f$ (and Frank answered that immediately), but elham's comment indicates otherwise. Perhaps elham wants to know if such an $f$ is studied in the literature, or perhaps elham really did mean multiplicative. In the latter case, though, I think it's worth discouraging the term "arithmetic" as a substitute for "multiplicative."

Comment: At any rate, their profile indicates OP hasn't been active here since roughly when the question was posted, so I'd rather more opportunity was allotted to fix the question before (disciplinary?) action is taken. (It takes much more community effort to open than to close, so I like the latter being relegated to a "last resort" type of decision. The ideal to me would be if close votes for poorly-worded questions were not handed out until they've been community-bumped once or else sufficiently edited by the OP with help.)

Comment: @anon,I said too hasty, I take it back.